# Highlight entire table row using CSS only

Tags: html, css, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to add some custom CSS to the [Angular Bootstrap UI Datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), which has been relatively easy so far. I've wrapped the `uib-datepicker` element in a div, and then use that div's id to alter this specific calendar.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-body confirmContent" id="calendarModal">
    <uib-datepicker id="datepickerWeek" ng-model="selectedWeek" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="datepickerWeekConfig"></uib-datepicker>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#calendarModal > .well > table thead tr th button:hover,
#calendarModal > .well > table tbody tr td button:hover,
#calendarModal > .well > table tbody tr td button.btn-info.active,
#calendarModal > .well > table tbody tr td button.btn-info.active:focus{
    background-color: #155f8e;
}
```

However now I need to highlight an entire `tr` based on when the `.btn-info` class becomes `.active:focus`. I've researched the [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) psuedo-class, however I don't think I'm getting the syntax right. Essentially what I want is something like this:

```
#calendarModal > .uib-datepicker > .uib-monthpicker > tbody tr:has(> td button.btn-info.active:focus)
```

Unfortunately this solution must be CSS-only. jQuery is verboten and since this is a third-party plugin I don't own the HTML in a view/partial somewhere. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not possible with CSS as there is no parent selector. You can't select UP the  DOM

Comment: Right, that is purpose of the `:has` selector. It is a roundabout way of selecting parent elements.

Comment: `:has` is not supported by any browser. Careful.  Just write some vanilla JS code to hack it.

Comment: Not like that...and it has *zero* support

Comment: AFAIK there is no CSS-only solution here since `:has` is not available in any browser . Maybe u need to hack the plugin yourself.  This is not that difficult tho. Just create a new function like `$scope.isRowActive` for every `tr` that checks the `$scope.isActive` value for every `td` in this row.

Comment: Gotcha... dissapointing such a basic operation was left out.